# SQL Server: INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE Timeouts

Tags: sql-server, timeout

Recently I've been having difficultly Updating records in a table due to them timing out.

I cannot update rows on the database or even create new tables through SQL Server Management Studio.

I've checked `sp_who2` and I don't see any ids in th BlkBy when saving the table. (I was just about to grab the error message but sods law, it worked this time, a recurring problem though so I shall still ask for assistance).

When the Update/Delete/Insert/Create statements are run they appear as status RUNNABLE.

The queries that are run are always very small.

Hopefully I've not been too vague but I'm sure to have missed some info out so if you have any ideas or questions it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide a couple sample statements?  The queries are small, but how large is the table?  Are you updating from a custom application you've written, or from mgmt studio?  Have you fired up perfmon (or similar) on the server to monitor it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new small table and check if
   it's working fine.
2. Check if you have indexes on the
   tables you updating on the fields
   you use in WHERE condition.
3. Check server log for errors.
4. Try to check/repair tables in
   databases.